# Difference between graph.layered and graph.trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I currently learn to use the `graphs` library from TikZ 3.0. What is the general difference between the graph drawing libraries `trees` (ch. 29) and `layered` (ch. 30)?

When should I use which library and which limitations do I have to consider when using `trees` or `layered`?

Here is a piece of code from chapter 29:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt, tikz]{standalone} 
% additional packages
\usepackage{amsmath, ifluatex, tikz}
\ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec                    % Spezifikation Zeichensatz
                    , lualatex-math     % Fixes for mathematics related LuaLATEX issues
                   }
\fi
% additional TikZ libraries
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
% graph drawing libraries
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [%
%                 layered layout
                  tree layout
                  ]
{ a -> { b -> c -> d, e -> f -> g } -> h };
\end{document}
```

Comment: What kind of difference are you looking for? When to use which, or how they work at a low level, etc?

Comment: When to use which and which limitations I have to consider. (I will add this sentence to my question.)

Comment: Doesn't the layered stuff offer finer-grained, more complex formatting? So you can combine layouts and do different things. That was my impression but I'm not certain. (So I'd think use the layered stuff when you need it and the simpler layouts when you don't.)

Comment: If trees is a subset of layered, I'm fine. Does anybody has certain information about this?